# groupBy multiple fields in Kotlin and sum values

Tags: kotlin, collections, group-by

Assume that I have data looks like the following

```
data class Student(val name: String, val room: Int, val sex: String, val height: Int, val weight: Double){}
```

and I have a list of students

```
val students = listOf(
     Student("Max", 1, "M", 165, 56.8),
     Student("Mint", 1, "F", 155, 53.2),
     Student("Moss", 1, "M", 165, 67.3),
     Student("Michael", 2, "M", 168, 65.6),
     Student("Minnie", 2, "F", 155, 48.9),
     Student("Mickey", 1, "M", 165, 54.1),
     Student("Mind", 2, "F", 155, 51.2),
     Student("May", 1, "F", 155, 53.6))
```

My goal is to group the students with the same room, sex and height and sum their weight

The final list should be like this

```
{
Student(_, 1, "M", 165, <sum of weight of male students who is in 1st room with height 165>),
Student(_, 1, "F", 155, <sum of weight of female students who is in 1st room with height 155>),
...
}
```

(The students' name can be omitted)

I already looked at [Nested groupBy in Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851138/nested-groupby-in-kotlin) but it did not answer my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you need to group by several fields you can use `Pair`, `Triple` or your custom data class as a key for grouping

```
val result = students
    .groupingBy { Triple(it.room, it.sex, it.height) }
    .reduce { _, acc, element ->
        acc.copy(name = "_", weight = acc.weight + element.weight)
    }
    .values.toList()
```

Comment: Use `fold(0) {...}` instead, reduce will throw exception if there is 0 or 1 element.

Comment: OwO, Kotlin docs are confusing they said it will throw, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html

Comment: @AnimeshSahu it will for regular arrays and lists, but not for [Grouping](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/) reduce

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I tried with 0 and 1 element and it does not throw any exception.

Comment: True, reduce only throws for Array and Lists https://pl.kotl.in/w3MW7hm5n the code above by IR42 is safe :)